# Exception connecting Excel to .Net Core v1.1 OData v4 Add at least one media type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Using `.Net Core v1.1` to create an `OData` service, it works fine connecting from a browser, though fails when connecting from Excel 2016, as a basic `OData` Feed. The Exception is

> 'InvalidOperationException'
>       No media types found in 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Formatter.ODataOutputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes'.
>       Add at least one media type to the list of supported media types.

Both Excel and the browser connect to ‘http://localhost:52315/odata’ with Method = ‘GET’

HeaderAccept from the browser is:

```
"text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*"
```

HeaderAccept from excel is: (NOTE: I added new lines after ';' for readability)

```
"application/json;
odata.metadata=minimal;
q=1.0,application/json;
odata=minimalmetadata;
q=0.9,application/atomsvc+xml;
q=0.8,application/atom+xml;
q=0.8,application/xml;
q=0.7,text/plain;
q=0.7"
```

Any insights into how a media type can be added, and which should be added is appreciated. Can't seem to find samples or previous questions dealing with this.

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently a known issue (cf https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/597). It seems unlikely that it's gonna be solved in the vNext branch, but fortunately, I found a workaround.

In your `Startup.cs`, just after registering Odata, add this snippet:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddOData();
    services.AddMvcCore(options =>
    {
        // loop on each OData formatter to find the one without a supported media type
        foreach (var outputFormatter in options.OutputFormatters.OfType<ODataOutputFormatter>().Where(_ => _.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
        {
            // to comply with the media type specifications, I'm using the prs prefix, for personal usage
            outputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.dummy-odata"));
        }
    });
}
```

This will find all the output formatters that don't declare a supported media type, and add a dummy one.

References:

- [vNext code that adds an improper formatter](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/maintenance-aspnetcore/vNext/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/Formatter/ODataOutputFormatters.cs#L44)
- [same code in the master branch](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Formatter/ODataMediaTypeFormatters.cs#L62)